# Is it possible to see the questions I have followed?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I don't know whether my question is duplicate.If so ,please flag it.

Is it possible to see the question in my profile after I has followed it?

I have checked it in my profile but nothing found.

[image]

Comment: From: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network): *"A tab for follows will be added to your user profile activity page"* - i.e. It's in the pipeline